# How to setting --token-auth-file for k3s

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, kubernetes-dashboard

We set up the k3s environment and to access the Kubernetes dashboard we use Kubernetes-dashboard. I want to use the --token-auth-file option for the static token in the k3s. After that, I want to use a static token login to the k3s dashboard.

How to do that any idea?